# Save jade file to html with same name

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, npm, pug

Trying to get jade to save my jade files as HTML files while keeping the same file name.

So the file `views/index.jade` should save as `dist/index.html`

Same for additional files.

I am using `grunt-contrib-jade`

The jade configuration of my Gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    jade: {
      compile: {
        options: {
          pretty: true
        },
        files: {
          'dist/*.html': ['views/*.jade']
        }
      }
    }

  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jade');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['jade']);
};
```

But it just saves the file as `*.html`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's doing what you are telling it to do.
Try this for configuration of the jade task:

```
jade: {
    compile: {
        options: {
            pretty: true
        },
        files: [{
            expand: true, // setting to true enables the following options
            cwd: '/jade', // src matches are relative to this path
            src: ['{,*/}*.jade'], // matches *.jade in cwd and 1 level down
            dest: 'dist/', // destination prefix
            ext: '.html' // replace existing extensions with this value
        }]
    }
}
```

[here is](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically) is some information about building file lists dynamically with Grunt.

Comment: I've used the {,\*/} glob pattern for a while without really understanding it. I now see that it matches either an empty string (what falls before the comma), or a directory name followed by a '/'. The other option is to use ['**/.jade'] to match .jade files in the src directory and all subdirectories.